# Improving the algorithm for removal of element

Tags: java, algorithm

## Problem

Given a string `s` and `m` queries. For each query delete the `K`-th occurrence of a character `x`.

For example:

```
abcdbcaab
5
2 a
1 c
1 d
3 b
2 a

Ans abbc
```

## My approach

I am using BIT tree for update operation.

Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ss.length(); i++) {

    char cc = ss.charAt(i);
    freq[cc-97] += 1;
    if (max < freq[cc-97]) max = freq[cc-97];
    dp[cc-97][freq[cc-97]] = i;                 // Counting the Frequency
}
BIT = new int[27][ss.length()+1];
int[] ans = new int[ss.length()];
int q = in.nextInt();
for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
    int rmv = in.nextInt();
    char c = in.next().charAt(0);

    int rr = rmv + value(rmv, BIT[c-97]);              // Calculating the original Index Value
    ans[dp[c-97][rr]] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    update(rmv, 1, BIT[c-97], max);            // Updating it
}
for (int i = 0; i < ss.length(); i++) {
    if (ans[i] != Integer.MAX_VALUE) System.out.print(ss.charAt(i));
}
```

**Time Complexity** is `O(M log N)` where `N` is length of string `ss`.

## Question

My solution gives me **Time Limit Exceeded Error**. How can I improve it?

```
public static void update(int i , int value , int[] arr , int xx){  
    while(i <= xx){
        arr[i ]+= value;
        i += (i&-i);
    }
}

public static int value(int i , int[] arr){
    int ans = 0;

    while(i > 0){
        ans += arr[i];
        i -= (i &- i);
    }
    return ans ;
}
```

Comment: Could you please show the code of `value` method? It would be good to know how large can `N` and `M` be and how large is time limit exactly.

Comment: What is a BIT tree? In particular, how do you interpret an `int[][]` as a tree?

Comment: And what is `in`? If it is an instance of `java.util.Scanner`, it might be too slow. Unbuffered output can also be the reason for bad performance.

Comment: The complexity won't be MlogN it would be M(log(N)^2)

Comment: Why it is off topic question regrading algorithms are not related to computer science , only question about **syntax** are consider on topic

Comment: Could you please add the entire code and constraints on n and m? I believe that the problem can be with i/o, but it is not possible to know it for sure without additional information.

Comment: @user2040251 you have said `in` can be slow should i used BufferedReader instead of Scanner

Comment: To answer this question, we need to understand your code, and that is pretty difficult. Consider using more descriptive names (in the age of code completion, there is really no reason to restrict names to one or two characters), and adding comments (for instance about the invariants of your data structures).

Answer (score 3):

There are key operations not shown, and odds are that one of them (quite likely the `update` method) has a different cost than you think.  Furthermore your stated complexity is guaranteed to be wrong because at some point you have to scan the string which is at minimum `O(N)`.

But anyways the obviously right strategy here is to go through the queries, separate them by character, and then go through the queries in reverse order to figure out the initial positions of the characters to be suppressed.  Then run through the string once, emitting characters only when it fits.  This solution, if implemented well, should be doable in `O(N + M log(M))`.

The challenge is how to represent the deletions efficiently.  I'm thinking of some sort of tree of relative offsets so that if you find that the first deletion was `3 a` you can efficiently insert it into your tree and move every later deletion after that one.  This is where the `log(M)` bit will be.